# explain query is not working in oracle db

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I use the following query in MySQL and it works fine:

```
explain SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM tableone where userid='abc'
```

I tried the same in Oracle but I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [905] [42000]: ORA-00905: missing keyword
 ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

When I execute explain query in mysql it result type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref etc.... how can i get that result from oracle

Comment: `explain` is handled quite differently in the two databases:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm.

Comment: as stated in [the oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm#16889) your are missing the keywords `explain PLAN FOR`.

Answer (score 8):

```
explain SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM tableone where userid='abc'
```

That is syntactically incorrect in **Oracle**. the correct syntax is:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR sql_statement;
```

See [**How to create and display explain plan in Oracle**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/05/31/oracle-explain-plan/).

For example,

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM EMP;

Explained.

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    14 |   518 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |   518 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

8 rows selected.
```

Alternatively, you could achieve the same in **SQL*Plus**:

```
SQL> set autot on explain
SQL> SELECT empno FROM emp;

     EMPNO
----------
      7369
      7499
      7521
      7566
      7654
      7698
      7782
      7788
      7839
      7844
      7876
      7900
      7902
      7934

14 rows selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    14 |    56 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |    56 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: When I execute this query in mysql it result type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref etc.... how can i get that result from oracle

Comment: @PriyankaShaju For that you need to tell us what those attributes are? It is quite obvious that `mysql` and `oracle` are different **RDBMS** products, so you won't have similar **naming conventions** etc.